# Vector vs. Array for Deck of Cards

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

So I am trying to make a deck of cards simulator in C++, and I was wondering, what should I use, a vector or an array?  I am aware of the different abilities of each, I just do not know which I should use to make a cohesive experience. The reason I need this is because I am making a text based game and I will have a minigame of poker in it.

Comment: A (double-ended) queue.

Comment: deck -> `deque` ;-) The end-user experience does not depend on the choice, your ease of implementation does though.

Comment: What operations do you need to perform on the deck?

Comment: Biggest difference is that a vector is resizable. Do you need to resize your deck of cards?

Comment: I will have to resize it.  Because I want to be able to add cards to the hand of any given player, and take cards away from the main deck.

Comment: That can be done with any fixed size array and one number.

Comment: @VladimirF - how do you propose to handle dealing variable-size hands to players from the main deck using arrays?

Comment: If you want to deal cards from one end only, then `std::vector`. Otherwise, `std::deque`.

Comment: @SteveTownsend you would have to do the shifts vector does for you manually, otherwise it is the same. Of course, vector is better.

Comment: Hey! Who's dealing from the bottom of the deck in a poker game?! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, the "default" choice should probably be either `vector` or `deque` whenever you look at "I need to store a number of things". Using a plain array is not beneficial, unless it's super performance critical.

Of course, you will need several collections, such as the hand of the player(s), the cards in use, cards not in use.

Using a standard container class (`std::vector` or `std::deque`) you have the advantage that you don't need a separate "how many cards does player X have", you can use `player[x]
.hand.size()` to determine that. (Players are of course also a collection class!)

Comment: Arrays should also be used when the memory is constrained and fragmentation is undesirable, such as embedded systems.

Comment: If it is a long-lived collection, and you use `reserve` to size the vector to begin with [and never grow it], there is no problem with fragmentation as such. The overhead of one pointer would require a huge number of vectors to make any big difference, I'd say.